# Retrieve all rows for specific text after grouping by application and user id

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

When a user completes a step digitally column `is_digitally_signed` changes to `YES`.
What I am trying to do: If any step is completed digitally I want to retrieve all rows for same `application_id` and `user_id`. Please check beneath my desired output.

**R code to replicate my dataset**

```
df <- data.table(application_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 user_id = c(123,123,123,456,456,456,789,789,789), 
                 application_status = c("incomplete", "details_verified", "complete"),
                 date = c("01/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "03/01/2018"),
                 is_digitally_signed = c("NULL", "NULL", "YES", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "YES", "NULL")) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

**With an output**

```
df
  application_id user_id application_status       date is_digitally_signed
              1     123         incomplete  2018-01-01                NULL
              1     123   details_verified  2018-01-02                NULL
              1     123           complete  2018-01-03                 YES
              2     456         incomplete  2018-01-01                NULL
              2     456   details_verified  2018-01-02                NULL
              2     456           complete  2018-01-03                NULL
              3     789         incomplete  2018-01-01                NULL
              3     789   details_verified  2018-01-02                 YES
              3     789           complete  2018-01-03                NULL
```

**My (unsuccessful) effort**

```
df %>% group_by(application_id,user_id) %>% filter_all(all.vars(. == "YES"))
```

**Desired outcome**

```
application_id user_id application_status       date is_digitally_signed
              1     123         incomplete 2018-01-01                NULL
              1     123   details_verified 2018-01-02                NULL
              1     123           complete 2018-01-03                 YES
              3     789         incomplete 2018-01-01                NULL
              3     789   details_verified 2018-01-02                 YES
              3     789           complete 2018-01-03                NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### dplyr

We can use `filter` with `any`, which checks for a given group whether there is at least one record with `is_digitally_signed == 'YES'`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(application_id, user_id) %>%
  filter(any(is_digitally_signed == "YES"))
```

or use the `all` function to subset groups where not all `is_digitally_signed == "NULL"`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(application_id, user_id) %>%
  filter(!all(is_digitally_signed == "NULL"))
```

### data.table

We can also use `data.table` since you've already loaded your data as a DT:

```
library(data.table)
dt = setDT(df)
dt[dt[,.I[any(is_digitally_signed == "YES")], by=.(application_id, user_id)]$V1,]
```

or with `.SD`:

```
dt[,.SD[any(is_digitally_signed == "YES")], by=.(application_id, user_id)]
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   application_id, user_id [2]
  application_id user_id application_status date       is_digitally_signed
           <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>              <date>     <fct>              
1              1     123 incomplete         2018-01-01 NULL               
2              1     123 details_verified   2018-01-02 NULL               
3              1     123 complete           2018-01-03 YES                
4              3     789 incomplete         2018-01-01 NULL               
5              3     789 details_verified   2018-01-02 YES                
6              3     789 complete           2018-01-03 NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

As there is only a single column to test, we can simply use `filter` with `any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(application_id,user_id) %>% 
    filter(any(is_digitally_signed  == "YES"))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   application_id, user_id [2]
#  application_id user_id application_status date       is_digitally_signed
#           <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>              <date>     <chr>              
#1              1     123 incomplete         2018-01-01 NULL               
#2              1     123 details_verified   2018-01-02 NULL               
#3              1     123 complete           2018-01-03 YES                
#4              3     789 incomplete         2018-01-01 NULL               
#5              3     789 details_verified   2018-01-02 YES                
#6              3     789 complete           2018-01-03 NULL
```

---

Or another option is using `%in%` to return a single `TRUE/FALSE` output that gets recycled

```
df %>% 
   group_by(application_id,user_id) %>% 
   filter("YES" %in% is_digitally_signed)
```

---

Or we can use `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(is_digitally_signed == "YES", application_id,user_id, FUN = any)),]
```